# Async linked list to and from async iterable

Tags: javascript, linked-list, iterator, async-await, generator

I'm working on some stuff that works better with (immutable async) linked lists such as this:

```
{ value: 'one', next: async () => { value: 'two', next: async () => null } }
```

Here `next` is an async function that returns either `null` or the next linked list. But I'd also be able to convert from and to iterables. So here is my `iterableToLinked` function:

```
Utils.iterableToLinked = async function(iterable) {
    var iterator = (iterable[Symbol.asyncIterator] || iterable[Symbol.iterator]).call(iterable);
    var cache = [];

    var listFromGenerator = async function(index) {
        var length = cache.length;

        if (index < length) {
            return cache[index];
        }
        else {
            var item = await iterator.next();

            if (item.done)
                return null;

            cache.push({
                value: item.value,
                next: async () => await listFromGenerator(length + 1)           
            });

            return await listFromGenerator(index);
        }
    };

    return await listFromGenerator(0);
};
```

That method should work with iterables and iterators (since if I understand correctly, iterators are also iterables but not the other way around), both async and sync, so I can pass arrays, generators and async generators to it.

For symmetry, I want the reverse function to return an iterable (not an iterator):

```
Utils.linkedToIterable = function(node) { 
    return {
        [Symbol.asyncIterator]: async function*() {
            var current = node;

            while (current) {
                yield await current.value;
                current = await current.next();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I'm still a little confused with the difference between (sync and async) generators, iterables and iterators, so I wonder if anyone can spot issues with my code.